# Roman number for lines in algorithm

Tags: algorithmicx

Similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18111/how-to-put-a-line-number-every-line-of-algorithmic), I have this minimal working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Some alg}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \REQUIRE a,b, c
            \STATE d = a + b + c
            \STATE d = d/2
            \STATE d = d/3
            \RETURN d
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

What I want is to number the steps as Roman (instead of Arabic).

What I tried:

1. `\begin{algorithmic}[\Roman{1}]` (line 7)
2. `\setcounter{ALG@line}{\Roman{0}}` (after line 7, following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599208/38244))
3. `\begin{algorithmic}[label=\Roman*]` (line 7)
4. `\renewcommand\theALG@line{\Roman{ALG@line}}` (from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78660/38244))

Comment: Roman, or roman?

Comment: @Bernard Either is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line number in an `algorithmic` environment uses counter `ALC@line`. Unfortunately, that counter is not documented, and its format used in printing is hard-coded to `\arabic`.

In the following example,

- `\theALC@line` replaces `\arabic{ALC@line}`
- `\setAlgoLinenoFormat{<an one-arg macro>}` is provided, so `\setAlgoLinenoFormat{\roman}` will set the line number to roman.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% patch env "algorithmic" to use \the<lineno counter>
\xpatchcmd\algorithmic
  {\ALC@linenosize \arabic{ALC@line}\ALC@linenodelimiter}
  {\ALC@linenosize \theALC@line\ALC@linenodelimiter}
  {}{\fail}

% use roman line numbers
\newcommand\setAlgoLinenoFormat[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\theALC@line}{#1{ALC@line}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Some alg}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \setAlgoLinenoFormat{\roman}
            \REQUIRE a,b, c
            \STATE d = a + b + c
            \STATE d = d/2
            \STATE d = d/3
            \RETURN d
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Some alg}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \setAlgoLinenoFormat{\Roman}
            \REQUIRE a,b, c
            \STATE d = a + b + c
            \STATE d = d/2
            \STATE d = d/3
            \RETURN d
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]